# How can multiple elements be equally padded over vertical space

Tags: html, css

If I have the following html/css how can I make it so that the content elements are equally spaced so that they take up the full area of the container - including the red area.

The padding between each element should be equal.

CSS only solution please.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.a,
.c {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.b,
.d {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content a">something</div>
  <div class="content b">something else</div>
  <div class="content c">something longer. something longer. something longer. something longer.</div>
  <div class="content d">not a lot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flexbox`

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.a,
.c {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.b,
.d {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content a">something</div>
  <div class="content b">something else</div>
  <div class="content c">something longer. something longer. something longer. something longer.</div>
  <div class="content d">not a lot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me as I am only targeting modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Would using `display:table` and `display:table-row` work in your case?

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display:table;
}
.content {display:table-row;}
.a,
.c {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.b,
.d {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content a">something</div>
  <div class="content b">something else</div>
  <div class="content c">something longer. something longer. something longer. something longer.</div>
  <div class="content d">not a lot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is causing the longer content to use more padding than the shorter padding, so not exactly what I was looking for.